# What does the "Purpose" section of a Software Project Plan describe?

Tags: planning, project-proposal

I am developing a Software Project Plan and I am referencing a template that seems to define the Purpose section as describing the purpose of the project plan, and not the purpose of the product for which the project plan is being developed.

So which one does the Purpose section describe:
A. The purpose of the project plan e.g in [this example plan](https://www.search.org/files/doc/Sample%20Project%20Plan.doc)?
or
B. The intended purpose of the end product e.g in [this template](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~hawkey/3130/ProjectPlanTemplate.doc)?

Comment: What template are you referencing?

Comment: Who developed the template? Who's consuming it? What's your organizational standard?

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the template you're referencing, I expect it's like the introduction section of a lab report: the introduction section introduces **the report** not the experiment that the report is about.

The Software Project Plan will have a different purpose from the product you're making. And the purpose of the product you're making should be defined in a requirements document of some description **not** the plan. Otherwise there is too much likelihood of contradictions.

So, to directly answer your question, the Software Project Plan's *Purpose* section should be about the purpose of **the plan** (option A): Are you time-limited? Are you resource-limited? Are you financially constrained? What assumed constraints was this plan produced under?

Comment: Here is the link to the sample plan I am using (from your answer it sounds like the purpose is about the plan not the product): https://www.search.org/files/doc/Sample%20Project%20Plan.doc but this template here suggests the Purpose is for the "project for which the Plan has been written". So Im not sure anymore: https://web.cs.dal.ca/~hawkey/3130/ProjectPlanTemplate.doc